# Recursive Generator for Permutations

Tags: python, recursion, generator, permutation

As the Title suggests I'm trying to create a recursive generator to find every permutation to a given list. Here is the function that i came up with, which does not work:

```
def Permutations(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        yield l
    else:
        for i in l:
            for j in Permutations(l[:i]+l[i+1:]):
                yield [i].extend(j)
            
l1 = [1,2,3]

for p in Permutations(l1):
    print(p)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "idk.py", line 11, in <module>
    for p in Permutations(l1):
  File "idk.py", line 7, in Permutations
    yield [i].extend(j)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: If you don't have to use generators/build this yourself, `itertools.permutations` is a really good option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple issues with your code

```py
def Permutations(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        yield l
    else:
        for idx, i in enumerate(l):
            for j in Permutations(l[:idx]+l[idx+1:]):
                yield [i] + j
                """ or
                lst = [i]
                lst.extend(j)
                yield lst"""
```

1. You were using the value `i` as an index for your list
2. `.extend` does not return anything, so you were getting your `NoneType` error

Comment: Well thanks, my mistakes were quite silly. In hindsight I should have probabily taken a quick break and look at it again before coming here.